# DLIB On visual studio 2015 throws a unresolved external error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, unresolved-external, dlib

I'm trying to run the face detection example provided by dlib. I have set up my library directories and my include folders. I've included source.cpp in the project, and have added the files from the externals folder into it as well. When I run the program it said to enable jpeg support by defining jpeg support, which i did, but then it wont compile and provide 2 similar errors about an unresolved external.

> unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall dlib::jpeg_loader::jpeg_loader(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (??0jpeg_loader@dlib@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl dlib::load_jpeg > >(class dlib::array2d > &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (??$load_jpeg@V?$array2d@EV?$memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1@D@dlib@@@dlib@@@dlib@@YAXAAV?$array2d@EV?$memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1@D@dlib@@@0@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)    DLIBtemplate

This is my code header:

```
#define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <iostream>
```

using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

Answer (score 1):

You have to define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT for all your .cpp files, not just one of them.  You set it as a compiler setting in your project, not by writing #define in one file.

Comment: By compiler setting do you mean a preprocessor argument? I have it set as a preprocessor.

Comment: That's what I mean. Obviously that isn't what you did though.

Comment: Really you should use cmake